# find duplicate rows in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to find duplicate rows in a jqgrid?

Comment: The bigger question is why you have duplicate rows in the first place. Are you sure that you do not have a bug in the rest of your application, and that you are using the proper key for your grid rows?

Comment: I am trying to load local data into the grid from beforeRequest method but when ever the grid reloads the beforeRequest event gets fired and the grid is populated with duplicate data.

Comment: How are you inserting data? Can you check to see if an ID is already in the grid before adding the same row a second time?

Comment: Yes there is, you can find both server side or client side if you want. For client side on Grid Complete function go through first TD of each tr and pickup the ID then use any javascript sort/search to highlight duplicates or remove them. (You can create it as a function and run it after every reload)